# for loop show error called offest Undefined

Tags: php

```
$size=$_POST['size']; //Post
$a=count($size); 
for($x=0;$x<$a;$x++)
{
    $f=$size[$x];
    echo $f;
}
```

above code returns error called  Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: What are you trying to loop? are you sure $size is an array?

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($_POST["size"]);` ?

Comment: Probably in `$size` you don't have a key 1, can you provide `var_dump($size)` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose an array like this:

```
$size = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'zar' => 'car'
];
```

In this case, `count($size);` will be 2, but the indexes `0` and `1` do not exist (it's an assoc array). That's why you'd be better of using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($size as $key => $value)
{
    echo '$size[' . $key . '] = ' . $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
$size[foo] = bar
$size[zar] = car
```

Of course, this all assumes `$size` actually is an array. You really ought to check that first:

```
$size = isset($_POST['size']) && is_array($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : [];//default to empty array
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest doing:

```
$size=$_POST['size']; //Post
foreach($size as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

as it is clean and concise

for multple arrays use:

```
$size=$_POST['size']; //Post
$size1=$_POST['size1']; //Post
foreach(array_combine($size,$size1) as $key=>$value) {
    print $key."<br/>".$value."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: $size=$_POST['size'];
$size1=$_POST['size1'];

Comment: @codefrenzy: Off-topic, but in both cases (1 and 2), I'd look into writing a function (recursive or otherwise)... DRY and all that

Comment: @kparsiya: in that case, post `size` as an array of arrays: `$size = $_POST['size']` where `$size[0]` is what `$_POST['size']` is now, and `$size[1]` is what `$_POST['size1']` is now etc..., then you end up with one array of size arrays

Comment: @Elias i have removed my comments and updated my answer. Thanks for your iinsights. :)

Comment: @kparsiya, you are not checking if your variable is set like so: `$size[$size[0]] = isset($size[0]) ? $size[0] : null;`. in `foreach` that problem does not happen

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing an array like `$size[$x]`, you are accessing the array `$size` with offset `$x`.

The notice `Undefined offset: 1` means that the array `$size` either isn't an array or doesn't have an element `1`.

In your case, I think `$size` is either:

- an associative array. This means it doesn't have numeric keys and therefore you won't be able to loop over it like that. Instead use something like this:

  ```
  foreach($size as $element) {
      echo $element;
  }
  ```

  This will also work with numeric keys, and is overall the cleaner approach.
- given that you are retrieving data from the `$_POST` superglobal, it is likely that the input supplied isn't an array. To debug it more, either use a debugger with your IDE or the good old `var_dump()`.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: i realised in the time it took me to write this many others have answered as well.

Comment: Another possible issue with `$size` is that it's a sparse array (think of: `$foo = range(1,10); unset($foo[1]);`)

Comment: True that. I've been doing more Java mostly and I have begun to appreciate that in Java arrays are just arrays, not crazy multi-faceted extra dimensional uber-memory wasting maps of anything.

Comment: a PHP array is, in Java terms, a Dictionary. Nothing more, nothing less. Its implementation isn't _that_ wasteful in terms of resources. It's OK, and the upcoming major release (PHPNG/PHP7) features a big revision of the array API, reducing its memory footprint further, and upping the speed. (off topic, but just so you know)

Comment: I hope i didn't sound too critical of PHP, as I use it every day and love it for what it does. I just wanted to point out that PHP arrays are much more than 'pure' arrays in other programming languages. :)

Comment: Well, I like PHP, too. That doesn't mean I can't criticize it (I do, often :-P). But to say a PHP array is a _"multi-faceted extra dimensional uber-memory wasting maps"_ is a bit too much. I'd stick to _"a PHP array is not an array, it's a dictionary"_. Their implementation isn't too different from a dictionary in other languages